# la différence de vs. de l'

Tags: articles

> J'ai peur de l'eau.

> J'ai besoin d'eau.

Pourquoi on ne peut pas omettre l'article dans la première phrase mais dans la seconde oui?

Answer (score 3):

Dans la première phrase, on désigne une chose particulière, l'eau. Un article est requis.

> J'ai peur de l'eau. (*I'm afraid of (the) water*)

Dans la deuxième phrase, ce qu'on souhaite dire, c'est :

> J'ai besoin <s>de</s> <s>de l</s>'eau. (*I need (some) water*)

comme on aurait pu dire :

> Il me faut **de l**'eau.

Il s'agit alors de la préposition ***de*** (avoir besoin de) suivie de l'article partitif ***de la***.

Cependant, on ne dit jamais *de de la*, cette forme est réduite en ***de*** (ici *d'* par élision) qui joue donc le rôle à la fois de préposition et d'article :

> J'ai besoin **d**'eau.

S'il s'était agit d'une eau déterminée, on aurait dit :

> J'ai besoin **de l**'eau (qui est dans ta bouteille). (*I need the water*.)

comme on aurait pu dire :

> Il me faut **l**'eau (qui est dans ta bouteille).

Comment: Merci beaucoup!